# Window docker can't do "apt-get update" from any linux repos

Tags: php, docker, debian, window

W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.

W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-all/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-all/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update   && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ git openssh-client libpng-dev   && docker-php-ext-configure intl   && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo_mysql zip' returned a non-zero code: 100

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0.30-apache
LABEL maintainer="Alefe Souza <contact@alefesouza.com>"

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ git openssh-client libpng-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
 && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo_mysql zip
```

Comment: Can you format your `Dockerfile` code so it matches what you have in the file? If you have one long line like it is in the example above, the \ before the `&& apt-get install...` and other `&&`s isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian site seems down, I also got 404 on the following:

cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the stretch release or can you switch to php:7.0.32-apache-jessie ?

I had the same issue this morning, and bypassed it by switching my base image from php:7.1.23-fpm to php:7.1.23-fpm-jessie

EDIT:
ignore the above, Debian seems to be having an outage, we just have to wait